# How to stop debugging in VS17 when pressing close?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and I am trying to understand how to transition between different windows.

I currently have two windows: a LoginWindow and a MainWindow. The LoginWindow opens first and transitions to the MainWindow. However, when this happens and I press close, the debugging in VS17 does not stop. Why is this and how can I make it work properly? I have looked around a bit whereas I found this:

```
<Application.MainWindow>
   <NavigationWindow Source="MainWindow.xaml" Visibility="Visible"/>
</Application.MainWindow>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. VS simply enteres "break mode"... :(

This is how my App.xaml currently looks like

```
<Application x:Class="LearningWPF.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearningWPF"
         StartupUri="LoginWindow.xaml">

<Application.MainWindow>
    <NavigationWindow Source="MainWindow.xaml" Visibility="Visible"/>
</Application.MainWindow>

<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

Any suggestions as to what I can do or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you still have the login window open.

What you can do is override the OnClose event and then forcefully close the application when the main window is closed. Write this in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);

    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

`Application.Current.Shutdown()` will ensure all the windows are closed on close of mainwindow.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Simple solution :D